# itelephony.aidl answerringingcall() doesn't work

Tags: android

I am trying to use ITelephony.aidl in my application. Using this i want to answer the incoming call. I managed to use endcall() and it works perfectly. But when i try to use answerringingcall() it throws error and says that MODIFY_PHONE_STATE is needed, but cant be used since its only available for system apps.

So is there any way of making this work on android 2.3 and above?or is there any other way for answering calls ?

thanks in advance:)

here's my code.

`

```
public void callAnswer(){


        try {
            Class c = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
            Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
            m.setAccessible(true);
            telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(telephony);
            telephonyService.answerRingingCall();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }`
```

and this is my ITelephony.aidl file

```
 package com.android.internal.telephony;
interface ITelephony {

 boolean endCall();

 void answerRingingCall();


}
```

Comment: Why there is down vote for the question?

Answer (score 2):

must add permission uses-permission android：name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"

Comment: i tried that, but apparently google blocked it and this feature doesnt work anymore since the app permission is blocked for system apps only. Or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: do you want to AutoAnswerPhon?

Answer (score 0):

May be @pra16 you have found a way to accept a call. If not check out this [link](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.devel/210104).The headset keyevent hack worked fine for me . I tested it on android 4.3